# Linear transformations making independent features dependent

Tags: machine-learning, classification, statistics, feature-selection

I read about features and some relevant topics recently. I ran into an easy but very advanced question:

> Why can two independent features become dependent after applying a linear transformation?

I think this is false, because:

> For $x_1$ and $x_2$, after linear transformation $y_1=ax_1+b$ and $y_2=cx_2+d$, $y_1$ and $y_2$ are independent.

Comment: space property is preserved only if the linear transformation is ‘similar'